# Recording Selenium test execution with Expression Encoder 4 SDK fails on build server

Tags: c#, selenium, teamcity, windows-server-2012-r2, expression-encoder-4

We run Selenium tests nightly on our TeamCity build server.

We have some tests that fail intermittenly during our nightly run.

Screenshots of failed tests haven't really provided an answer, so I want to record the execution of failed tests.

I have implemented the following to record test execution of tests I want to investigate.

```
        ScreenCaptureJob = new ScreenCaptureJob
        {
            CaptureRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds,
            ShowFlashingBoundary = true,
            OutputPath = outputPath
        };

        ScreenCaptureJob.Start();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Status: {ScreenCaptureJob.Status}");

        Test code...

        ScreenCaptureJob.Stop();
```

If the test fails I encode the captured video and save it.
This works fine when I run the test locally.

But, when I run this on the build server the ScreenCaptureJob has a status of NotStarted.

No temp file is written to disc, so there is nothing to encode when the test fails.

```
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(fileName);
        Job job = new Job();
        job.MediaItems.Add(mediaItem);
        job.ApplyPreset(Presets.VC1HD720pVBR);
        job.OutputDirectory = outputPath;
        job.Encode();
```

Exception occurs when I try to create a new MediaItem from the temp file.

```
TestCleanup method UITests.FailingTest.TestCleanup threw exception. Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.InvalidMediaFileException: Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.InvalidMediaFileException: File not found.
```

EE4 is installed on the build server, and I have tested capturing with the EE4 program itself.

Does anyone have an idea of why the ScreenCaptureJob fails to start on the server?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem with ScreenCaptureJob.

Answer (score 1):

Running tests on Windows Server require you to add the feature

> User Interfaces

and

> Infrastructure > Desktop Experience

to install missing dependencies required by Microsoft Expression Encoder.

If you already did this and it doesn't work read [this article](https://decoupledlogic.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/video-recording-c-webdriver-tests-in-testpipe/), it is very helpful and there is a link to GitHub profile with the code used for the video recording. The author uses ScreenCaptureJob thru interface which sounds great.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Both features are enabled on the server. As I said initially, tests are running on the build server. And recording with ScreenCaptureJob works fine when running the tests locally. It just doesn't work on the server.